# changing a role with html select box asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the ASP.NET web application template and trying to allow a user to pick a role when registering.

Here is what I got at the moment.

Does it

View

```
    <fieldset class="col-lg-5 .col-md-5">
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.TypeList)
        </p>

        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-default" />
    </fieldset>
```

Model

```
  public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeList
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "athlete", Value = "athlete"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "coach", Value = "coach"},
    };
        }
    }

}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Type);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I am feel like I am close but I can't quiet get it and i am getting this error

Compiler Error Message: Models.RegisterModel>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize your model in HttpGet Register method? Like below...

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        var model = new RegisterModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

I create an empty template MVC4 app, added your code, got object reference not set error as default Register model does not pass model object to view which you are trying to access (i.e. loading TypeInt in DropDownListFor()).

I then initialized model in Get method as shown above. All works fine, i was able to pick a role on register view.

Check if this helps.

Comment: Yesss now the page is loading! however it seems to be saying system.web.webpages.html.selectlist item inside the option selector box.

Comment: Didn't get you? Are you still getting error? You can update your question with specific more details.

Answer (score 0):

take a look your last comma should be removed:

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "athlete", Value = "athlete"},
new SelectListItem { Text = "coach", Value = "coach"}
```